# How to calculate time intervals between events in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

I have a table called Events. It has Computer_Id, User_Id, Event_Type and Event_DateTime. When an user logs into a computer, Events table gets an entry for that login, similarly for logout from all computers in the network. The requirement is to find how much time  a computer was in use or how much time a given user spend on a computer or can be how much time all computers were in use, that is the 
time interval between the logins and logouts, for a given day  lets day where Event_DateTime>='2018-04-26 00:00:01' and Event_DateTime>='2018-04-26 11:59:59'.  The trick part is sometimes a login  might not have associate logout and vice versa.
I will highly appreciate your insights to approach this problem. Thank you Login = 43 and Logout = 42
[image]

[Sample Data Link for test.bak](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1nx1s4u22d0bfjo/test.bak?dl=0)

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Can a computer be in use continuously for more than 1 day?

Comment: Yes. User can come and login then later after 10 mins might go for coffee, so the computer send event as logout. User can many times in a day login and logout.

Comment: I just updated the question with snap shot of some data. EventType is Int type, Login=43 and Logout = 42. Thank you

Comment: @Rohit Did you want to get user Login and logout record on every current day?

Comment: @ D-Shih, day shouldnt matter because that will be passed from Admin UI, and insert in where clause where EventDateTime>=varible and EventDateTime<= varible. So it could be by day or month.

Comment: @Rohit Ok I see,What's your expect result? the pic is sample data right?

Comment: for example, computer_Id (2315278A-240C-487C-9E3E-897B0284EB52) , InUsed( 30 minutues), so on. I can then pass conditions to the query to fatch result for all computers, or by users( how much time user used that computer) and so on. I will convert these minutes to appreciate display for UI.  The crazy thing Entity framework is slow, and doesnt have much options available,in compare to Direct SQL .

Comment: The idea is to check how given a computer id, how much time it was in Use, or given a user id , how much it spend on a computer.

Comment: @Rohit I See,Could you provide some sample data from source? Not the pic, provide some format or text data.and what's your sqlServer version?

Comment: Just added sample data from real database, there are other Event Types ,please ignore those. Server version 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correct,you need to use `CROSS APPLY`on subquery to get the most close date by `logout`.

like this.

```
 SELECT t1.Computer_ID,
         t1.User_ID,
         CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(s, DATEDIFF(s,t1.Event_time   ,t2.Event_time), 0), 108) 'castTime' 
  FROM T1 t1 CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT TOP 1 * 
      FROM T1 t2
      WHERE t2.EventType = 43 
          AND t1.Computer_ID = t2.Computer_ID
          AND t1.User_ID = t2.User_ID
      ORDER BY Event_time DESC
  ) t2
  WHERE t1.EventType = 42 
  and t1.Event_time BETWEEN '2017/10/10' and '2017/10/11'
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4703f/2*

**Edit**

This query is calculation cost totle time by every computer.

If that didn't your expect,Could you provide your expect result from my sqlfiddle sample data?

```
SELECT t1.Computer_ID,
       CONVERT(char(10), t1.Event_time,126) 'Dates',
       Convert(VARCHAR,DATEADD(ms,SUM(DATEDIFF(ms, '00:00:00.000', castTime)),'00:00:00.000'),108) 'totleCastTime'
FROM T1 t1 CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT TOP 1 *,
             DATEADD(s, DATEDIFF(s,t1.Event_time,t2.Event_time), 0) 'castTime'
      FROM T1 t2
      WHERE t2.EventType = 43 
          AND t1.Computer_ID = t2.Computer_ID
      ORDER BY Event_time DESC
  ) t2
  WHERE t1.EventType = 42 and t1.Event_time BETWEEN '2017/10/10' and '2017/10/11'
GROUP BY  t1.Computer_ID,
          CONVERT(char(10),t1.Event_time,126)
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4703f/23*

Comment: Thanks. but the result that is required is to find out for how much time  a computer was in use, so the result would for computer A , it was used for 30 mins or for 55 minutes and so on. Its to count times between login and logout then count the all to get total time that computer was in use.

Comment: it looks good. So I pass clauses to it and get results. What  will I do if EventTypes are NOT in consecutive order and if an event is missing. Like if one logout is missing. Lets say Admin selects todays date but when I convert that date to BETWEEN '2018-04-24 00:00:01' and '2018-04-24 11:59:01', if user logged at 11:45pm yesterday and logout at 30 mins later, i will get only one logout but not its pair login. Is there a way to insert a fake login time stamp?

Comment: there test.bak file I have here, you can see sometimes, computers report 2 or 3 same events at the same time.

Comment: @Rohit some reason I couldn't open the test.bak could you provide the CREATE TABLE and INSERT Data script be a file?

Comment: Were you able to open the file ?

Comment: @Rohit Yes the file I can read well.Sorry for reply you so late.What's your expect fake login timestamp when user logged at 11:45pm yesterday and logout at 30 mins later? Is the search condition `EventDateTime` LoginTime interval?
this link query  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6a8bd0217aa81b239a1d598581ec4010 `EventDateTime` is for search LoginTime interval.

Comment: fake login timestamp can be anything really as long as it does give wrong results. so in ideal situation, the events should be like login,logout,login,logout,login,logout, but it we have like login,logout,login this one has missing logout we can end fake it here to give it logout just after login.

Comment: @ D-shil , is it possible to get data that are pairs and ignoring the ones that aren't, so if the table in given daytime range , has login login and then logout , ignore the first one , and so on ? Thank you ..

Comment: @ D-shil, is it possible to get logins and logouts in pairs and ignore the ones that does have matching login or logout, order by computerId? really appreciate your help.